# Rational Clearcase Explorer has stopped working bug

Tags: clearcase

I'm using Clearcase 7.1.2 with Windows 7 64 bit.
I'm getting crashes repeatedly (seemingly when I use the scroll bar - though I'm not positive that is always the case).
Looking at the event log I see:

```
Faulting application name: clearexplorer.exe, version: 7.1200.0.214, time stamp: 0x4c87f2c3  
Faulting module name: clearlist.ocx_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4c87f0ab  
Exception code: 0xc0000005  
Fault offset: 0x03597c1f  
Faulting process id: 0x16e4  
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdb2ddb53e24d7  
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\clearexplorer.exe
Faulting module path: clearlist.ocx  
Report Id: f29793dd-1eda-11e2-b4a5-0023ae7ecd09
```

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to fix this?
`clearlist.ocx` would seem to be the culprit, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  ClearCase can crash every few minutes, which is driving me nuts.

Comment: - Read [this](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.platforms.doc/topics/r_win_win64.htm) - Check if upgrading to latest version (7.1.2.8) helps: [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21611347](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21611347)

Comment: It appears our site has its own repository of allowable updates, so I am limited to updating to 7.1.2.3.  Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Admin manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_ms_platforms_guide.doc/clearcase_on_windows.htm) does mention:

> Rational ClearCase clients have several limitations when hosted on 64-bit Windows platform.
>   Most of these limitations are related to dynamic views.
>   For additional information about Rational ClearCase and 64-bit Windows platforms, see the IBM [Software Support Web site for Rational ClearCase](http://www.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/support/index.html).

The [Help page for 7.1.2](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.platforms.doc/topics/r_win_win64.htm) echoes that, albeit for Windows Xp (I suppose it extends to Windows 7 as well, but this is not confirmed):

> Rational® ClearCase® clients have several limitations when hosted on 64-bit Windows platforms such as Windows XP Professional x64 Edition.
>
> - The Rational ClearCase integration with Windows Explorer does not work with the 64-bit version of Windows Explorer. To enable this integration, run the 32-bit version of Windows Explorer.
> - The Rational ClearCase remote client and other Eclipse-powered software is not supported on 64-bit Windows platforms.

This [system requirements for ClearCase 7.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974) does include [several limitations](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974#Footnote%201), including the [technote "
**Known limitations using Rational ClearCase on 64-bit Windows platforms**"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247988).

Ideally, ClearCase 8 has a better 64-bit support for Windows (even though you can find [instruction to install ClearCase on Windows 64bits for CC7.1, 7.1.2 and 8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21567211)).

The usual issue with ClearCase Explorer on Windows 64 bits is [related to the contextual menu (not there)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM62172).
But I only saw intermittent crashes in one case: dynamic view scanned by an antivirus (so try and see if the crashes still occur when - temporarily - de-activating the antivirus)

Answer (score 0):

Create a C:\temp directory if you don't already have one.
Set your environment varibles for both User and System to C:\TEMP
Right click the C:\temp directoy and select properties.
Select the Security tab.
Grant the USERS FUll permissions.
Click OK. 
Reboot the workstation.

Comment: What environment variable(s) am I setting?